# Tune output markup for code block in Jekyll (kramdown)

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

Jekyll (kramdown, actually) turns code

````
```xml
    <code here/>
```
````

into HTML block

```
<div class="highlight">
    <pre>
        <code>
            ...
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Is this possible to add another class and atributes to this block? I mean to get something like this

```
<div class="highlight hl-js" data-js="bla-bla">
    <pre>
        <code>
            ...
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put an extension directive after your block, like this:

```
~~~xml
    <code here/>
~~~
{: .hl-js data-js="bla-bla"}
```

Documented in http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#block-attributes

Comment: Thank you very much. This is nice. However I meant to add the class and the attribute to all the code blocks automatically but leant that gh-pages do not allow Jekyll plug-ins.